# Is there a way to suppress the "Data connections have been blocked" warning in Excel when running a VBA macro from a Word document

Tags: excel, ms-word, data-connections

I have a Word document (.dotm) with an embedded graph.

When the document opens, I want to read data from a file on the local machine and add the data to the workbook associated with the embedded graph.

However, when I open the file, I get the following error

[image]

I know I can suppress this by enabling all content in Trust Centre | External Content | Enable All Data Connections. But as Excel warns you, this is not recommended, and it appears a rather drastic solution.  Is there any other way to get rid of this warning?  I just want the macro to run without the user having to click "Enable" every time.